# How to create a DASH VOD for Chromecast with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, chromecast, google-cast, mpeg-dash, shaka

I need to serve long videos (~2 hours) from a web server to mobile clients and the clients should be able to play the videos via `Chromecast`. I have chosen `mpeg-dash` for this purpose: video encoder is `h.264` (level 4.1), audio is `aac` (although I've tried diffrent ones).

I've tried `ffmpeg`, `MP4Box` and some other tools to generate videos; most of the time I succeeded playing them on VLC or on a mobile client (locally), but not with Chromecast.

I've tried Amazon's `Elastic Transcoder` and it worked, but it gave me one big file whereas I need many small segments.

CORS are set.

Chromecast remote debugging didn't help much.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to do it. This is the script that converts a video file to dash with many segments which can be played by Chromecast:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 8 \
-i input.ts \
-c:v libx264 \
-x264-params keyint=60:scenecut=0 \
-keyint_min 60 -g 60 \
-flags +cgop \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-coder 1 \
-bf 2 \
-level 41 \
-s:v 1920x1080 \
-b:v 6291456 \
-vf bwdif \
-r 30 \
-aspect 16:9 \
-profile:v high \
-preset slow \
-acodec aac \
-ab 384k \
-ar 48000 \
-ac 2 \
output.mp4 2> output/output1_ffmpeg.log \
\
&& MP4Box -dash 2000 \
-rap \
-out output/master.mpd \
-profile simple \
output.mp4#video output.mp4#audio 2> output/output2_mp4box.log
```

As you can see, first I encode the input file; then I use `MP4Box` to convert it to dash. Note that Chromecast can fail playing video with more than 2 audio channels (I use 2 with `-ac 2`).